# Workstation GC in .NET Core 3.1 is not working for AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, garbage-collection

I am creating an AWS Lambda function with .NET Core 3.1 and I have a problem with increased memory consumption.
For this reason, I wanted to use Workstation GC as this setting reduces memory consumption by several times.

I set **ServerGarbageCollection** setting to **false** in the *.csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AWSProjectType>Lambda</AWSProjectType>
    <!-- This property makes the build directory similar to a publish directory and helps the AWS .NET Lambda Mock Test Tool find project dependencies. -->
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
    <ServerGarbageCollection>false</ServerGarbageCollection>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

and after building the project in ***.runtimeconfig.json** these lines have been added

```
"configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": false
    }
```

after these changes, when checking the garbage collector mode, the **GCSettings.IsServerGC** property is always **true**.

I tested it on a regular console application and it works fine, but as soon as I connect the aws lambda libraries, the application becomes like a class library and it is impossible to change this setting. I searched the aws documentation but didn't find anything that could help me.

q: how do I enable Workstation GC in AWS Lambda?